# Quarkus LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization when running super-heroes workshop

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

I´m new to Quarkus so I was starting with the Quarkus super-hero workshop available [here](https://quarkus.io/quarkus-workshops/super-heroes) yet I´ve found a problem that seems to be already reported and solved in [issue 23660](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23660) when running in dev mode:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization for class io.agroal.pool.util.XAConnectionAdaptor: when selecting method 'javax.transaction.xa.XAResource javax.sql.XAConnection.getXAResource()' the class loader 'platform' for super interface javax.sql.XAConnection, and the class loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @398c8a2 of the selected method's class, io.agroal.pool.util.XAConnectionAdaptor have different Class objects for the type javax.transaction.xa.XAResource used in the signature (javax.sql.XAConnection is in module java.sql of loader 'platform'; io.agroal.pool.util.XAConnectionAdaptor is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @398c8a2, parent loader 'app')
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:226)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:535)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:516)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        ... 1 more
```

Yet I´m still getting this problem running tests while starting the aplication in dev mode using the maven command `./mvnw quarkus:dev` . Running standalone tests also with maven `./mvnw test` all tests are passing without any problem.

Once I´ve notice that this problem was reported before to be a dependency concurrency problem I´m also providing the pom of `rest-villains` module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.quarkus.workshop.super-heroes</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-villains</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

**How to Reproduce?**

Run the workshop, at least, until [this step](https://quarkus.io/quarkus-workshops/super-heroes/#_building_production_package).

**Quarkus version**

2.16.1.Final

**Environment**

Apache Maven 3.8.7 (b89d5959fcde851dcb1c8946a785a163f14e1e29)
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Default locale: pt_PT
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

I cannot find any more information about this problem, so if someone hit a similar situation I would be very grateful for any aditional information to overcome the described problem.

Thank you

---

**Solution Update**
For some reason, I had a (not needed) depedency to javaee-api in my rest-villains module and that was the cause of the described problem.

After removing the dependency from rest-villains POM, the described problem was gone.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Big thanks to Clement

Comment: Your module depends on `javaee-api`. The workshop does not mention this dependency. Any reason to have it?

Comment: Hi @Clement you hit the point! That´s completly correct, this dependency was the cause of this problem and is not needed indeed. Thank you very much.